# How to change CSS of ng-view when triggering CSS in ng-include

Tags: css, angularjs, css-animations

I have included my left-hand, vertical navbar into the page using `ng-include`.
My navbar expands right on hover. Each page is wrapped in `<div class="wrapper">`.

I am trying to change the margin of each wrapper as the navbar pushes right on hover so that when a user hovers over the navbar, it doesn't overflow into the page text. However, my CSS does not work with angular because the header is in `ng-include` and the pages are in `ng-view`.

How can I get this to work?

Here's my **css**:

```
.wrapper {
    margin-left: 12em;
}

nav:hover .wrapper {
    margin-left: 25em;
    transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Here is a plunker of the problem: http://embed.plnkr.co/R1G1AFTMQjEhdaqB66U3/
As you can see, the TEST text does not move.

Comment: So if I understand correctly you want the page margin to dynamically move the content over when a user hovers over the navbar?

Comment: Yes. It works when I run the website non-angular. But when I put the navbar as a template for `ng-include`, it does not work.

Comment: Can you create a Plunker or JSFiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: @mcgraphix http://embed.plnkr.co/R1G1AFTMQjEhdaqB66U3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your CSS is trying to target the .wrapper div that exists inside the nav:hover which isn't how you HTML is set up. You can get pretty close to what you want with a simple HTML change and one additional class in your CSS:

First add a class on your include so we can capture when it is hovered and target the node that follows it:

```
 <div class="menu-holder" ng-include='"header.html"'></div>
```

Then, instead of this:

```
 nav:hover .wrapper {
     margin-left: 25em;
     transition: all 0.5s;
 }
```

Use this

```
 /*Add animation to the div that follows the menu holder*/
 .menu-holder + div {
   transition: all 0.5s;  
 }
 /*target the div that follows the .menu-holder div and apply this when hovering */
 .menu-holder:hover + div {
   margin-left:25em;
 }
```

See http://embed.plnkr.co/dW64avra2sh299z3e7wc/